# Checking data match and mismatch between two columns using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Sample data below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jleBB.png)

input of file A and File B is given and the output format also given . can someone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

I'd also be curious to see a clever/pythonic solution to this. My "ugly" solution iterating over index is as follows:

dfa, dfb are the two dataframes, columns named as in example.

```
dfa = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['v','f','h','m','s','d'],'c2':['100','110','235','999','333','39'],'c3':['tech','jjj',None,'iii','mnp','lf'],'c4':['hhh','scb','kkk','lop','sos','kdk']})
dfb = pd.DataFrame({'c1':['v','h','m','f','L','s'],'c2':['100','235','999','110','777','333'],'c3':['tech',None,'iii','jkl','9kdf','mnp1'],'c4':['hhh','mckkk','lok','scb','ooo','sos1']})
```

Now let's create lists of indexes to identify the rows that don't match between dfa and dfb

```
dfa, dfb = dfa.set_index(['c1','c2']), dfb.set_index(['c1','c2'])
mismatch3, mismatch4 = [],[]
for i in dfa.index:
    if i in dfb.index:
        if dfa.loc[i,'c3']!=dfb.loc[i,'c3']:
            mismatch3.append(i)
        if dfa.loc[i,'c4']!=dfb.loc[i,'c4']:
            mismatch4.append(i)
mismatch = list(set(mismatch3+mismatch4))
```

Now that this is done, we want to rename dfb, perform the join operation on the mismatched indexes, and add the "status" columns based on mismatch3 and mismatch4.

```
dfb = dfb.rename(index=str, columns={'c3':'b_c3','c4':'b_c4'})
df = dfa.loc[mismatch].join(dfb)

df['c3_status'] = 'match'
df['c4_status'] = 'match'
df.loc[mismatch3, 'c3_status'] = 'mismatch'
df.loc[mismatch4, 'c4_status'] = 'mismatch'
```

Finally, let's get those columns in the right order :)

```
result = df[['c3','b_c3','c3_status','c4','b_c4','c4_status']]
```

Once again, I'd love to see a prettier solution. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here are **four lines of code** that may do what you are looking for:

```
columns_to_compare =['c2','c3']
dfa['Combo'] = dfa[columns_to_compare].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[x.notnull()]), axis = 1)
dfb['Combo1'] = dfb[columns_to_compare].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[x.notnull()]), axis = 1)
[i for i,x in enumerate(dfb['Combo1'].tolist()) if x not in dfa['Combo'].tolist()]
```

**explanation**

Assume that you want to see what **dfb** rows are not in **dfa**, for columns **c2** and **c3**.

- To do this, consider the following approach:

Create a column "Combo" in **dfa** where each row of "Combo" contains a comma separated string, representing the values of the chosen columns to compare (for the row concerned)

```
dfa['Combo'] = dfa[dfa.columns].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x[x.notnull()]), axis = 1)

    c1  c2  c3   c4     Combo
0   v   100 tech hhh    100, tech
1   f   110 jjj  scb    110, jjj
2   h   235 None kkk    235
3   m   999 iii  lop    999, iii
4   s   333 mnp  sos    333, mnp
5   d   39  lf   kdk    39, lf
```

Apply the same logic to **dfb**

```
    c1  c2  c3   c4     Combo1
0   v   100 tech hhh    100, tech
1   h   235 None mckkk  235
2   m   999 iii  lok    999, iii
3   f   110 jkl  scb    110, jkl
4   L   777 9kdf ooo    777, 9kdf
5   s   333 mnp1 sos1   333, mnp1
```

Create a list containing the required indices from dfb:

```
[i for i,x in enumerate(dfb['Combo1'].tolist()) if x not in dfa['Combo'].tolist()]
```

or to show the actual row values (not indices):

```
[[x] for i,x in enumerate(dfb['Combo1'].tolist()) if x not in dfa['Combo'].tolist()]
```

**Row Index Result**

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

**Row Value Result**

```
[['110, jkl'], ['777, 9kdf'], ['333, mnp1']]
```